# Zend framework quickstart index file is not working

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi guys i am new to Zend framework and today only i have started learning it.so my first step is i am installing ZF1 in my system so i have done the steps which is need for install from below link `https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html`

And when i run `http://localhost/quickstart/`

it is showing index of those files it is not running index.php file

can any one help me what mistake i have done and i am using the ubuntu server

below are the things which i had followed i had downloaded it downlaoded two zip files  one is zendAuth and another one is and zend framework 1.12.20 
and i have create one folder names quickstart and and i have moved those files to to inside quickstart.

So now my files are in under the `/var/www/quickstart/zendAuth/Zemdframeowrk 1.12.20`

And i have made `php.ini` change in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` and in that i have made  `include_path = ".:/var/www/quickstart/zendAuth/library"`

and after that in `apache2.conf` file at the end of file i have added the below   code

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName quickstart.local
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/quickstart/zendAuth/public

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

        <Directory /var/www/html/quickstart/zendAuth/public>
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

And in hosts file at the top  of the file i have added this  `127.0.0.1    quickstart.local`

Can any one check and let me where i have done mistake and please help me out.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below configuration and then set .htaccess for root and public folder:

1) Entry in hosts file as below

```
127.0.0.1       quickstart.local
```

2) Set virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName quickstart.local
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/quickstart/zendAuth/public"
    ServerAlias quickstart.local
    <Directory "/var/www/html/quickstart/zendAuth/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3) Check root htaccess as below

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes
```

4) Check htacess in public folder as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
```